# Editing multiple jobs on Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I need to add the retry functionality to a number of jobs. Is it possible to edit multiple jobs at the same time, if its the same edit on all the jobs?

For example, I want to add 3 retries to every job.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I had to add the same options to a number of jobs.  I don't think you can globally edit all jobs in gui at once.

My jobs are committed to git as xml.  I checked out the repo, edited all job xml files I wanted to change, then commit/push.  On rundeck server gui I chose the 'import from scm' option to apply the changes I made in xml files.

Another alternative is to create a library job.  If you see jobs repeating same steps, make those repeated steps into a new job.  Then have all your other jobs call the library job. This takes some planning tho.